# How can I have a child Page manipulate its parent Page's properties, UI elements, and methods?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, uwp

My parent page has a toolbar on it. Then it has a `Frame` element located under the toolbar where the child page(s) get loaded. Is there a "correct" way of manipulating the toolbar located in the parent page from within the child pages that I navigate to? The parent page also has other properties that I would like to manipulate as well.

```
<Page>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="ToolbarRowDefinition" Height="46" />
            <RowDefinition x:Name="ContentRowDefinition" Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <local:MyToolbar x:Name="Toolbar"
                         Grid.Row="0" />

        <Frame x:Name="ChildFrame"
               Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I didn't think it would be a bad idea to attempt this since I don't know of any rule against it. All of this is located within the View, and so I don't think that there is a problem trying to access other View-level elements, methods, and properties from within other Views. Correct me if I'm wrong, though. Thanks!

Comment: So, if you get an instance of the Parent page in the child page, you will be able to access it's public properties.. is that what are you asking for?

Comment: Well, I'm aware that there are ways to access the parent's data. I just wanted to know if it was appropriate to do so, and which method(s) are most appropriate if any.

Comment: The other way which I think is if you have an instance of ParentViewModel, rather than instance of a parent view in child view, this might be a best approach to update parent's control states. But since I am not sure what elements you want to update and if you want to achieve this, you might require to change your xaml - like bounding some elements to ViewModel properties and need to do some extra stuff. But this is always a good approach so far I believed.

Comment: There is nothing wrong to update something in the parent from child using a code-behind approach by having an instance of a view in child. But hope you make sure you pass the same instance to child so that the changes will reflect.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite usual to create a "Shell" page, which contains a app-wide navigation structure and has a `Frame` inside which actually displays the content of your app.

There are many ways to communicate from the page with the shell. The easiest solution would be to provide a `public static` method in the shell that returns the current instance. Let's suppose the shell page is called `ShellPage`, then the method would look like this

```
public static ShellPage GetForCurrentView() => (ShellPage)Window.Current.Content;
```

There are several considerations to this:

- This method can be only called from the UI thread, but it is in line with many parts of the UWP API and it will work even if your app has multiple views or windows - it will always return the `ShellPage` for the window where the request is coming from.
- The code presumes the `ShellPage` is the main content of the `Window`. This is not the default, because by default in `App.xaml.cs` the `OnLaunched` method sets the root content to a `Frame` which is then navigated to a `MainPage`. It is perfectly fine to override this behavior and put `ShellPage` as the root of the window. If you don't want to do that, you would have to change the above code to `(ShellPage)((Frame)Window.Current.Content).Content` instead.
- If you want to have multiple views and some may not have a `ShellPage`, you may want to update the code to use `as` to make sure you are getting a `null` instead of an exception in case the `ShellPage` is not there. But that really depends on your specific scenario.